# Algorithm to get progressively closer to a number without ever reaching it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to have a number that gets updated progressively closer to the max (or min) value, without ever reaching it. I also would like each update to have a smooth transition, like a curve or something (I have never studied math or computer science so I don't know the correct terminology)

Here's what I got so far but it obviously doesn't work:

```
let numberToUpdate = 5 // this number will vary after each update
const numberToUpdateMin = 1
const numberToUpdateMax = 10

let someValueA = 100 // this number will change randomly between updates
let someValueB = 50 // this number will change randomly between updates

function updateNumber() {
  let differenceBetweenValues = someValueA - someValueB

  if (differenceBetweenValues > 0) {
    // make numberToUpdate closer to numberToUpdateMax (without ever reaching it)
    numberToUpdate += (numberToUpdateMax - numberToUpdate) * (someValueA / someValueB) // this doesn't work at all
  }
  else if (differenceBetweenValues < 0) {
    // make numberToUpdate closer to numberToUpdateMin (without ever reaching it)
    numberToUpdate -= (numberToUpdate - numberToUpdateMin) * (someValueB / someValueA) // this doesn't work at all
  }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, I have no clue what I'm doing or what terms I should be googling to arrive to a suitable result.

Edit: It doesn't have to work with infinitely small/big numbers, it could have a cap.

Comment: you are looking for some [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) behaviour.

Comment: Is the value you want to get close to known ? Or, are you searching for an unknown solution for a given equation ?

Comment: the value to get close to is `numberToUpdateMax` or `numberToUpdateMin` depending on what `someValueA` and `someValueB` happen to be at the time.

Comment: We may need to think carefully about the 'without ever reaching it' requirement as, although it deals always in floating point numbers, there are limits in JS which has only 64 bits in total to store fp numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of an asymptotic function:

```
function generateAsymptotic(step) {
  return step / (step + 1);
}
```

As step gets bigger, generateAsymptotic will get closer and closer to 1, but never be 1.

Comment: Past the value 4503599627370495, the function returns 1.

Comment: Yes, it's fine in theoretical arithmetic but not on a finite machine.

Answer (score 0):

On a computer, this is impossible, because the number of distinct values representable is finite, so in the end you will reach the forbidden number.